# Windows Phone SDK for Windows 7x64 and Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone, windows-7-x64

I am trying install Windows Phone SDK for PhoneGap, but when I was installing Windows Phone SDK 7.1, but doesn't work, because it si for VS2010. And Windows Phone SDK 8.0 etc. is maybe only for OS Windows 8. Do you have any ideas for solve this?

I have **Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate**.

Answer (score 1):

You need windows 8 or 8.1 x64 to install the windows phone sdk 8.0.  You will need the pro version if you want to use the emulators.  Of course your processor must support slat for the emulator also.

Comment: Is there any other option? I mean like some Windows SDK for W7x64 and VS12 Ultime?
BTW: Thank you for the advice, which I was afraid. :D